# Why using $p=y'$ doesn't lead to answer in $y^2(1+y'^2)=4$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the ODE $y^2(1+y'^2)=4$ to solve this I used the substitution $y'=p$
$$y^2(1+p^2)=4$$
$$2y(1+p^2)dy+2py^2dp=0$$
$$(p^2+1)dy+py\;dp=0$$
$$\frac{dy}y+\frac{p}{p^2+1}dp=0$$
$$\ln|y|+\frac12\ln|p^2+1|=\ln|c|$$
$$y\sqrt{p^2+1}=c$$
Using $p^2+1=\frac4{y^2}$, I get $2=c$ ! I can't find my mistake.

Comment: You differentiate from line 1 to 2, and then intergrate from line 4 to 5. So you did nothing.

Comment: @ArcticChar Oh, I realized my mistake, after differentiating I had to divide the equation by $dx$ and using $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$. But still have three variables, $p(p^2+1)+py\frac{dp}{dx}=0$

Comment: $2=c$ is not a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't make a mistake, but you have arrived back to the original equation. Note that $c$ can also be $-2$.

$$y\sqrt{p^2+1}=\pm2\implies y^2(1+p^2)=4$$

Instead, note that the differential equation is separable. It can be written as

$$y'=\frac{\sqrt{4-y^2}}{y}\quad\text{or}\quad y'=-\frac{\sqrt{4-y^2}}{y}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can I continue from $(p^2+1)dy+py\;dp=0$ and divide the equation by $dx$ ? I got $p(p^2+1)+py\frac{dp}{dx}=0$. which I don't know if it is possible to continue solving.

Comment: Then you have both $y$ and $p$, so the substitution $y'=p$ doesn't simplify the problem. It is much easier to solve by separating.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've only circulated in the differential equation. You have written the  series of steps only to arrive at the restatement of the original differential equation.

From your solution,

$$y\sqrt{p^2-1} = c$$
or $$ y^2 (p^2-1) = c^2$$
which is restatement of the original equation and $c^2 = 4$ only satisfies the condition of the original differential equation. Therefore you need to try to solve it in such a way that 4 does not get removed. One way could be to rewrite it as follows:

$$ y'^2= \frac{4}{y^2} - 1$$

This will lead to solution.

Answer (score 1):

*Alternative solution strategy:* Expanding the left side, you get a circle equation
$$
y^2+(yy')^2=4
$$
that can be parametrized as $y=2\sin u$, $yy'=2\cos u$ which then leads to
$$
y'=2u'\cos u\implies 2\cos u=yy'=4u'\sin u\cos u\implies x+c=-2\cos u
$$
if $\cos u\ne 0$. Then
$$
y^2=4(1-\cos^2u)=4-(x+c)^2.
$$